# Tcl Thread : How to access global variables in thread

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I have a proc named "startMyProc {num}". I want this proc to be called by two different threads and wait for both the threads to complete. I tried the solution given which is working. I want to access the global variables in startMyProc and call a another proc "startMyAnotherProc {num}". How can this be done?

```
package require Thread


global myVar

set myVar false

set id1 [thread::create -joinable {
    source sample.tcl
    thread::wait
    }]
set id2 [thread::create -joinable {
    source sample.tcl
    thread::wait
    }]

set num 1
thread::send -async $id1 [list startMyProc $num]
set num 2
thread::send -async $id2 [list startMyProc $num]

thread::join $id1
thread::join $id2

My sample.tcl looks like this,

proc startMyProc { num } {
    global myVar
    puts $myVar
    puts "Opening $num"
    after 2000
    puts "Opening $num"
    after 2000
    puts "Opening $num"
    after 2000
    startMyAnotherProc $myVar
    return
}

proc startMyAnotherProc { num } {
    puts "Opening Another Proc: $num"
    after 2000
    puts "Opening Another Proc: $num"
    after 2000
    return
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each thread has its own complete interpreter, isolated from all the other interpreters in your program (except for the `thread` package's commands' capabilities). The simplest, most direct way of getting the procedure in all the threads is to put it in a script file and then `source` that as part of the startup script of the thread:

```
set t1 [thread::create -joinable {
    source myProcedures.tcl
    startMyProc $num
}]
set t2 [thread::create -joinable {
    source myProcedures.tcl
    startMyProc $num
}]
```

You'll run into another problem though. Variables are *also* not shared. That means that you're not going to get `$num` over. You should really make the scripts start up and then do `thread::wait` at the end. You can then `thread::send` them the work (and get the substitutions right when building the script).

```
set t1 [thread::create -joinable {
    source myProcedures.tcl
    thread::wait
}]
set t2 [thread::create -joinable {
    source myProcedures.tcl
    thread::wait
}]
thread::send -async $t1 [list startMyProc $num]
thread::send -async $t2 [list startMyProc $num]
```

However, if you are really thinking in terms of sending tasks to worker threads, you should look at the thread pool ([`tpool`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tpool.htm)) support; it's *much* easier to scale up.

```
# Make the thread pool
set pool [tpool::create -initcmd {
    source myProcedures.tcl
}]

# Sent the work into the pool as distinct jobs
set job1 [tpool::post $pool [list startMyProc $num]]
set job2 [tpool::post $pool [list startMyProc $num]]

# Wait for all the jobs in the pool to finish
set waitingfor [list $job1 $job2]
while {[llength $waitingfor] > 0} {
    tpool::wait $pool $waitingfor waitingfor
}

# Get results now with tpool::get

# Dispose of the pool
tpool::release $pool
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.It worked. I have one more doubt. I have "startMyProc {num}" which has many global variables. How to access those variable without sending them as arguments?

Comment: The [thread shared variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tsv.htm) stuff might be suitable. I've not experimented with it very much.