# tpool use to speed up computation

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I try to use tpool to speed up the shasum computation of any files with size between 30 and 300 MiB in some folders.
I use tcl-tk version 8.6.6 from homebrew on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (the tcl-tk OS X version is 8.5.9 and the result is same but terminate with an error).
As I can understand the result of command “brew info tcl-tk”, tcl is compiled with option :
*—with-threads
    "Build with multithreading support"*

Without thread usage, it’s clear the CPU load (Activity Monitor) isn’t very busy.
With threading of tpool, not more, and time spend to compute a set of shasum files is globally the same.

Depending of -maxworkers number, the global % CPU of perl5.18 processes (shasum is a Perl script) is the same. Everything happens as if all the threads that work at the same time do it on the same processor core.

See below the main script based on an example from [Donald Fellows answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622243/tcl-thread-how-to-access-global-variables-in-thread):

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- tcl -*-
# The next line is executed by /bin/sh, but not tcl \
exec /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/bin/tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

package require Thread

set pool [tpool::create -maxworkers 16 -initcmd {
    source myProcedures.tcl
}]

proc TREE_parse_big_files {path} {
    foreach f [ glob -nocomplain ${path}/* ] {
        puts "Parsing ${f}"

        if { [ file type ${f} ] == "link" } { return }

        if { [ file isdirectory ${f} ] } {
            TREE_parse_big_files ${f}
        } else {
            tpool::post $::pool [list computeSHA ${f}]
        }
    }
}

TREE_parse_big_files  “/tmp/BigFiles” $pool

# Dispose of the pool
tpool::release $pool
```

The file myProcedures.tcl contains:

```
proc computeSHA {bigFile} {
    puts [eval exec shasum -a 256 -b {$bigFile}]
}
```

Is there something I didn't understood?

Comment: Most likely your program is I/O bound and not CPU bound.  It takes time to read all that data off the disk drive.   If you have the memory available, try loading a bunch of files into memory and then computing the SHA on the in-memory data with different thread pool allocations.

Comment: Thanks Brad for your answer. You are right.
Sorry, I haven’t enough memory to allocate 7 GiB (my data set) of RAM disk.
I’ve tried with a limited set of data on a RAM disk but I'm too limited and it’s not representative.
Anyway, for my first tests, the data was on an internal HDD. With your suggestion, I tried to compute SHA data on internal SSD.
The result is good.
With a single thread and always the same data set, the process finish in 1’04’’
With 8 threads, the process finish in 0’25’’
Same time with 16 threads
The best value for the number of threads is 4, in this configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately the data are on external drives (USB, Firewire, thunderbolt) and the time spend to compute SHA will be very long… So, the threading will definitely not a good idea to reduce this time in my process.
My next step will be to estimate if I can gain time with a file copy from external Hard Drive to RAM disk and SHA computation. As I have also some works to do on the files… it's worth to be tried. Thanks

Comment: Ultimately, when looking at improving performance you have to first figure out where the bottleneck is. Adding threads can improve CPU utilisation (and also memory utilisation, though that's not always a good thing), but if you're really just waiting for I/O (either disk or network) then adding threads just lets you do nothing in parallel.

Comment: Your test does show that the procedure is I/O bound.   I would definitely test out the copy-first scenario.   But ultimately, you will end up waiting for the file reads to finish.